# What is the meaning of an explanation

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, knowledge, definitions, knowledge-representation

I am a software engineer and recently got involved in a community project that aims to teach underprivileged kids. This got me thinking about the term 'explanation'. What I want to ask is- what in your understanding does the concept of explaining mean? And what are the characteristics of a good explanation?

PS: It's my first question and I am not completely sure if this question belongs to this site. If wrong, let me know. I'll migrate it to the appropriate site.

Comment: See also [Scientific Explanation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-explanation/).

Comment: The concept of "explanation" changed in time: from a more natural [causal explanation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-causality/): the "reason why", to a type of explanation based on a [mechanism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-physics/) to a more modern reduction to [fundamental laws](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/laws-of-nature/).

Comment: There is a number of theories for scientific explanation alone, see e.g. [IEP's Theories of Explanation](http://www.iep.utm.edu/explanat). look also at Novotná's [Teachers' Views and Use of Explanation](http://people.fjfi.cvut.cz/novotant/jarmila.novotna/NovotnaSEMT05.pdf) for the pedagogical angle. There are also Mathematics Educators and CS Educators SEs that can offer more subject specific advice.

Comment: i think i know this when we explain something we know that it "had to happen". 95% sure that was on a lecture handout. though there are many different "why questions". see [salmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wesley_C._Salmon)

Answer (score 1):

When I explain things, I try to put myself in the listener's situation. It is important to know the background of the listeners, their level of understanding the subject. Try to identify their misunderstandings. I think there is not a better way of understanding than confronting your own misconceptions.
A good explanation is an explanation that is appropriate for the level of understanding of the listener and suited for the listener's way of learning.
Try to add analogies and (mental) pictures in your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the term explaination generally refers to  the ability to transmit or exchange  epistemic  justification through narrative. Basically, explainations answer the question of "how" from the perspective of "why".